# Comparing Two Dataframes Columns against a third column in Second DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare two different dataframes for column "Source2/Source3" against "Spider". If they are a match then create column True/False. Secondly, If there is a match (True) then I want to make sure column "Product_ID' in scheduler_df is 12345. If this is the case then mark 'True' else 'False'.

So far in my code, I am already comparing both dataframes to make sure Source and Spider match. I am struggling in comparing it now to the product_id column.

consolidate_df

```
Source2      Source3
Jen_Arrest    Jen_Jail
Ben_Arrest    Ben_Jail
```

scheduler_df

```
Spider      Product_ID
Jen_Arrest   88888
Ben_Arrest   12345
```

Current Code:

```
consolidate_df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, consolidated_fn), sheet_name='Poseidon-2')
scheduler_df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, scheduler_fn))

consolidate_df['isScheduler'] = consolidate_df['Source_2'].isin(scheduler_df['Spider']) | consolidate_df['Source_3'].isin(scheduler_df['Spider'])
```

final df:

```
Source2      isScheduler   isProd
Jen_Arrest   True         False (because 8888 does not match 12345)
Ben_Arrest   True         True (because 12345 matches 12345)
```

Comment: 'consolidate_df['isProd']=scheduler_df['Product_ID']==12345 '

Comment: Thats just looking at scheduler_df for 12345. It is not taking into account the boolean consolidate_df['isScheduler'] = consolidate_df['Source_2'].isin(scheduler_df['Spider']) | consolidate_df['Source_3'].isin(scheduler_df['Spider']). If that boolean is True then I want to look at scheduler_df for string 12345. Needs to compare column Spider with Source for same name (i.e. Jen_Arrest == Jen_Arrest)

Answer (score 0):

we can create the testing for the product_id in scheduler_df:

```
 scheduler_df['prod_test']=scheduler_df.Product_ID.apply(lambda x:True if x==12345 else False)
```

then we create our column isProd:

```
consolidate_df['isProd']=consolidate_df['isScheduler'] & scheduler_df['prod_test'] | consolidate_df['isScheduler'] & scheduler_df['prod_test']
```

Comment: Somehow need to do something like this (syntax is most likely wrong), look at the last & statement......:consolidate_df['isProd'] = (consolidate_df['Source_2'].isin(scheduler_df['Spider']) | consolidate_df['Source_3'].isin(scheduler_df['Spider'])) & (scheduler_df['Product_ID'] == 12345). I think your solution is putting true if its 12345 but its not matching it back to the column scheduler_df['Spider'].isin(consolidate_df['Source'])